# How can we add by standard to opinion polls a "This is a stupid question" option?

Tags: public-opinion, polling, political-research

Standard opinion polls include after the options related to the question also a "Don't know/No answer" option. But often responders who choose that option had a feeling that the poll was based on a loaded question or other classic problems caused by the [wording](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opinion_poll#Wording_of_questions). In this case another option of the kind  "This is a stupid question" or an option like "I disagree with the wording of the question" would allow them to better express their opinion.

Of course, pollster who make a poll based on a loaded question would not be eager to add such an option. But if it were a standard the absence would be noticed. Would it be possible to turn into a standard?

Comment: Every attempt to reason about your views and give fact-based answers is countered by you with "but that is not what I proposed!" That is an opinion-based question if I ever saw one and warrants a close vote.

Comment: Voting to close - This question invites speculative reasoning. (And the answer is also obvious - the only way to enforce something like this is by regulation or law.)

Comment: In addition to the opinion based answers this question will produce, it is based on some fundamental misunderstandings in regards to polling. Polls are not a public service. They are a privately funded action. I say action because some polls are not for information gathering, but to push propaganda themselves. The majority of them are never revealed publicly. This question is basically asking for a law to be written to regulate polling at the same time as establishing a specific purpose for polling.

Answer (score 1):

"Stupid" is a rather loaded word, but it may happen that the question has been really badly prepared: contains wrong information, embedded propaganda, drags in unwanted side approval or written in a way so foggy that part of answers are likely random: *do you oppose not restricting limitations of permissions do X without approval*?

For instance, Switzerland has recently [rejected](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-6913533/Swiss-referendum-overturned-voters-given-incorrect-information.html) results of the referendum on the taxation of married couples, because of voters told 80,000 married couples were penalised but it was nearer 454,000. Even more, the original question was [likely worded](https://lenews.ch/2016/02/25/helping-a-few-at-the-expense-of-many-swiss-vote-against-penalising-marriage/) so that it would indirectly but officially restrict the definition of the family to ‘a union of a man and a woman’ that was not the question under discussion there. The Christian Democratic People’s party’s proposal goes as far as writing this definition into the constitution. This forced voters opposing this side effect to vote against regardless of they position to the main question.

Saying something along the lines "this question is not fit" would likely enhance the right of voters and contribute to democracy.

Comment: In general, polling companies work for (and serve the interests of) an employer, rather than democracy.

Comment: Then is even more likely that the question may be drafted to push the needed point of view, no not properly fit. Allowing to answer so puts some control in case when even if preferred result is known, these who ordered pool would like to know exactly the truth.

Answer (score 0):

- A good poll typically has only a small minority of response in the "Don't know/No answer" category. There is no need to split it further.
- Even the current "Don't know/No answer" option presents enough challenges with data analysis. Including "This is a stupid question" presents even more challenges.
- Perhaps "This is a stupid question" option can be used in **pilot** polling, with a subsequent interview with the people who selected it, to better understand the issue, and to improve the final poll questions. I do not recommend it in the final poll.

---

**References:**

Example poll 1 (only a minority of the responses are in N/A category):

[image: example poll 1]

*[Views on Voting and the Political Parties - The New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2014/02/26/us/political-parties-poll.html)*

---

Example poll 2 (only a minority of the responses are in N/A category)

[image: example poll 2]

*[An Indirect Path to Accuracy in Election Polling - The New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2014/05/23/upshot/an-indirect-path-to-accuracy-in-election-polling.html)*

---

> [...] you should always pilot surveys whenever you can. Pilot both versions, see who uses the "don't know" category in the one where it's included, and look at the distribution of responses. And talk to the people who filled it out. "Were you sure of your answer?" "What made you say 'don't know' here"- that kind of thing.

[Should a multiple choice poll contain a neutral response?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/6628/76547)

---

> When people are asked to report their attitudes and beliefs in surveys about health issues (e.g., knowledge, risk), “I don’t know” (DK) is a common response that may undermine survey validity (1). Missing data due to survey nonresponse is an issue that is pervasive across survey research (2,3). Managing DK responses analytically can be done through different approaches (2–5). For example, DK responses can be excluded as missing data, presumed to mean “neither” and recoded as a neutral midpoint in a Likert response scale (6), or treated as a meaningful categorical response (5). However, there is no clear best practice, and each approach has limitations.
>
> Most commonly, DK responses are treated as missing data and excluded from analysis (1,7,8). Extensive DK reporting therefore results in large amounts of missing data and threatens the validity of study findings. For example, excluding DK responses from analyses reduces statistical power and could increase the chance of making a Type II error (i.e., failure to detect an effect that is present) (4). Also, exclusion of DK responses could bias the study sample. Literature reviewed here mainly focuses on health behavior research and risk perception. In these studies, individuals who provide DK responses tend to have lower health literacy and are at greater risk of health disparities (1,6,7,9). DK responses are also associated with lower education, lower numeracy, lower income, and minority status (1,6). Systematically excluding DK responses therefore hinders generalizability of research findings and ability to understand whether psychosocial constructs differentially influence behavior for populations at greatest risk for disease.

*[Denman DC, Baldwin AS, Betts AC, McQueen A, Tiro JA. Reducing "I Don't Know" Responses and Missing Survey Data: Implications for Measurement. Med Decis Making. 2018 Aug;38(6):673-682. doi: 10.1177/0272989X18785159. Epub 2018 Jul 2. PMID: 29962272; PMCID: PMC6076331.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6076331/)*

Comment: In your answer you carefully avoided to cite loaded questions as examples. It is biased.

Comment: @FluidCode I do talk about good polls and also about improving polling. I am biased - but in favor of improving poll quality, not making it worse.

Comment: My question is about giving to the responder the ability to express a judgement on the quality of the poll. An improvement in the quality coming from above is unlikely. Too many polls are made to support some kind of propaganda.

Comment: @FluidCode The polls usually include a pilot phase. As I mentioned, perhaps this option can be included in the pilot phase, to make the final version of the poll better. The final version of the poll should not include this option, for the reasons I outlined.

Comment: Polls well done have a pilot phase. Polls designed to be misleading on purpose do not have a pilot phase.

Comment: @FluidCode Polls designed to be misleading on purpose are also unlikely to include such an unusual, self-deprecating and introspective option as "This is a stupid question". They are bad polls, after all.